# UIAlertController gives sigabrt error if a cell in Table View tapped again

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

AlertController works fine in each cell of Table View when tapped. After pressing "OK" in the alert, when I click on the same cell again which was clicked earlier, it gives sigabrt error. No idea what to do here. Here is the code:

```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! JobsTableViewCell
    cell.jobTitle.text = jobTitle[indexPath.row]
    cell.jobDescription.text = jobDetail[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! JobsTableViewCell
    cell.jobTitle.text = jobTitle[indexPath.row]
    cell.jobDescription.text = jobDetail[indexPath.row]

    displayMessage(titleAlert: jobTitle[indexPath.row], userMessage: jobDetail[indexPath.row])
}
```

Comment: Where is this jobTitle global variable coming from? Why is it a global?

Comment: @Msencenb It is this class's variable, and values are added in it in ViewDidLoad()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your didSelect should look like below.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    displayMessage(titleAlert: jobTitle[indexPath.row], userMessage: jobDetail[indexPath.row])
}
```

There is no need to dequeue again in didSelect